# How to relapse/substitute data in cell in smart table for specific columns name using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

How to relapse/substitute data in cell in smart table for specific columns.

This is what I have so far. Currently code delete/substitute data for all columns.

```
Sub delete_data()
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim xWs As Worksheet

    For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If xWs.Name = "SheetTest" Then
            For Each lo In xWs.ListObjects
                For Each lc In lo.ListColumns
                    If lc.Name Like "Week starting" & "*" Then
                        lc.DataBodyRange.Replace What:="[*]", Replacement:=""
                        lc.DataBodyRange.Replace What:=" ", Replacement:=""
                    End If
                Next lc
            Next lo
        End If
    Next xWs
End Sub
```

Comment: You can call `Replace` on the entire `lc.DataBodyRange`. You don't need to loop cell-by-cell.

Comment: @BigBen Thank you. Now it works... and works fast ;)
But, in case we need to replace data in cell if Len(cell) = 1 and only for specific columns?
How to proceed? Thank you.

Comment: @Alex_D.  `lc.DataBodyRange.Replace What:=" ", Replacement="", lookAt:=xlWhole` will only replace on cells where exact match in cell is the `What:=` criteria ... all that said, you changed your question in the comment, so it's probably better to create a new question (or edit this question) and show the code you have tried to solve your problem and where it's not working.